# Join two Json arrays to one with key and value postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have two jsonb columns(keys,values). Eg: keys colum value = `["key1","key2","key3","key4"]` values column = `["val1","val2","val3","val4"]`

I want to write a select query to get the output as below based on the array index.

```
{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":"val4"}
```

The problem is the array size wont be fixed. Each row contains different size. But keys and values column size will be always same.

Comment: I got the solution here. From Stack Exchange. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291088/join-two-json-arrays-to-one-with-key-and-value/291089#291089

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is the `json_array_elements` function to explode the JSONs and  the `json_agg` to recompact them

I replicated your case with

```
create table jsonb_test (a jsonb, b jsonb);
insert into jsonb_test values ('["key1","key2","key3","key4"]','["val1","val2","val3","val4"]');
```

And the query solving the problem is

```
with row_tbl as (
select 
 replace(cast(json_array_elements(a::json) as varchar),'"','') k, 
 replace(cast(json_array_elements(b::json) as varchar),'"','') v
from jsonb_test)

select json_agg(
json_build_object(k,v)) as complete_json
from row_tbl
;
```

Answer (score 0):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddl](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1063f4474169b1594c68cfc5b82686a9)e

```
SELECT
    json_object_agg(                                       -- 3
        keys ->> gs,                                       -- 2
        vals -> gs                                         
    )
FROM 
    mytable,
    generate_series(0, json_array_length(keys) - 1) as gs  -- 1
```

1. Create the indexes for access the array elements. For that: Count elements of the keys (`json_array_length()`) and generate an index series.
2. Now you can use the created indexes to access both, the `keys` and the `values`
3. Create a new JSON object by aggregating the extracted key/value pairs